# get Postgres UDT value with JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

In Postgres, i created a UDT as follows

```
CREATE TYPE MY_TYPE AS ENUM ('FAILED', 'SUCCESS');
```

and in postgres cli, i can retrieve the UDT value back like

```
\dT+ MY_TYPE
```

which lists the details of the UDT, including its enum values under the 'Elements' column

EDIT: added result of "\dT+" command

```
postgres=# \dT+ status_type
                                         List of data types
 Schema |    Name     | Internal name | Size | Elements |  Owner   | Access privileges | Description 
--------+-------------+---------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------
 public | status_type | status_type   | 4    | WAITING +| Postgres |                   | 
        |             |               |      | STARTED +|          |                   | 
        |             |               |      | PAUSED  +|          |                   | 
        |             |               |      | SUCCESS +|          |                   | 
        |             |               |      | FAILED   |          |                   |
```

Now, I am using JOOQ in a spring project, and want to get that UDT's value using JOOQ. Can anyone help me on how to get that done?

NOTE: I know that JOOQ generates the ENUM types when generating classes, But is that the only way to get the information i need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get a listing of all the enum literals from the database, dynamically. The SQL query that the jOOQ code generator uses for this similar to this:

```sql
SELECT n.nspname, t.typname, e.enumlabel, e.enumsortorder
FROM pg_enum e
JOIN pg_type t ON e.enumtypid = t.oid
JOIN pg_namespace n ON t.typnamespace = n.oid
ORDER BY n.nspname, t.typname, e.enumsortorder
```

Now, just run this query using jOOQ like any other query to get something like this ([from the Sakila database](https://www.jooq.org/sakila)):

```
nspname |typname     |enumlabel |enumsortorder |
--------|------------|----------|--------------|
public  |mpaa_rating |G         |1             |
public  |mpaa_rating |PG        |2             |
public  |mpaa_rating |PG-13     |3             |
public  |mpaa_rating |R         |4             |
public  |mpaa_rating |NC-17     |5             |
```

Comment: I believe the query you mentioned gives the list of enums available. But, what I'm looking for is to get the values defined for a particular enum. I've edited the post to show what the "\dT+" command returns. So, is there is a way to do that in jooq, or to execute any of Postgres's meta-commands ?

Comment: I'm also aware that there is query based approach to do this. But, I want to know if Postgres meta-commands can be executed through JOOQ. If not, I can fall back to the query based solution

Comment: Yeah, gee, add a filter to the query already :) No, jOOQ doesn't interpret those psql specific commands. If you're using plain SQL, jOOQ will just send everything to the JDBC driver, and that also doesn't support anything like `\dT+`...